# How does this follow as a corollary?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In my notes I have that if $\alpha \in B$ is integral over $A$ then $A[\alpha]$ is finitely generated as an $A-$module. However, my professor says right after that it follows as a corollary that $B',$ the set of elements of $B$ that are integral over $A$ is an subring of $B$ that is integral over $A.$ Clearly the only thing we have to see is that $B'$ is a subring over $B$ as integral over $A$ is immediate by definition. But the ring structure of $B'$ is clear without the lemma stated at the beginning. So how is this a corollary?

Comment: How is it clear that the difference and product of integral elements is integral? With the corollary, you get that they are both in $A[a][b]$, which is finitely generated, and hence that $A[a-b]$ and $A[ab]$ are both finitely generated.

Comment: Oh no. I for some reason thought that the $a + b$ would be the zero of the polynomial $f + g$ where $f, g$ have $a, b$ as zeros respectively.  Thank you.

Comment: even if that were the case, if $f$ and $g$ are both monic, then $f+g$ is *not*, so it wouldn't help you at all...

Comment: I need more sleep :(